# Storm - KafkaSpout fails on open()

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

For the past two days, I’ve been tying to implement a KafkaSpout within our topology. Here 
are some important information.

All three services are running on the same instance. Kafka’s brokers use as by default the 9092 
port, with `advertised.listeners` set to `PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`. Zookeeper, uses the default 
client port 2181. Whereas the Storm Nimbus host name has been set to localhost as well.

A custom Kafka Producer creates log messages successfully, whereas by using the zkCli 
Zookeeper script I’ve seen that when using the /brokers path, the partitions and other relevant 
information are stored correctly.

However, I keep getting the error when activating, and afterwards monitoring the topology. 
Here is the source code of the Storm topology I’ve implemented:

```
BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("127.0.0.1:2181");

SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "bytes", "/kafkastorm/", "bytes" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
spoutConfig.zkServers = Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1");
spoutConfig.zkPort = 2181;

KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("bytes", kafkaSpout);
builder.setBolt("byteSize", new KafkaByteProcessingBolt()).shuffleGrouping("bytes");

StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();

Config config = new Config();

StormSubmitter.submitTopology("topology", config, topology);
```

However, the error message I keep getting when executing the `bin/storm monitor <topology_name> -m bytes` is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: stream: default not found
at org.apache.storm.utils.Monitor.metrics(Monitor.java:223)
at org.apache.storm.utils.Monitor.metrics(Monitor.java:159)
at org.apache.storm.command.monitor$_main.doInvoke(monitor.clj:36)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at org.apache.storm.command.monitor.main(Unknown Source)
```

Whereas by inspecting the logs of the workers (the worker.log file), I’ve concluded that 
the KafkaSpout fails on the open() method.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy
at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:75) ~[storm-kafka-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7990$fn__8005.invoke(executor.clj:604) ~[storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.curator.RetryPolicy
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
... 5 more
```

Could someone explain what might be the reason for the KafkaSpout to fail on the 
open() method?

I would really appreciate for your help!

Comment: What version of Kafka and Storm you are using? Also look at the version of storm-kafka. Are you using HDP cluster?

Answer (score 0):

From the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy" it appears that curator-client.jar is missing.

Please check if below link helps you ?

https://github.com/abhinavg6/Kafka-Storm-Conscomp/issues/1